# How can I locally store a button clicked counter on individual buttons with the same class?

Tags: javascript, php, html, local-storage, counter

I have a lot of buttons and I am trying to permanently keep a counter on the buttons that are clicked but they all share the same class.  How can I get the individual counts for each button instead of all the buttons with the same class?

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
<script>
function clickCounter() {
    if(typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
        if (localStorage.clickcount) {
            localStorage.clickcount = Number(localStorage.clickcount)+1;
        } else {
            localStorage.clickcount = 1;
        }
       if(localStorage.clickcount > 3){
           document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "You have exceeded your download limit for this product.  Contact Support.";
       }
    } else {
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Sorry, your browser does not support web storage...";
    }
}
```

**PHP/HTML**

```
$host = "localhost";
$userid = "root";
$password ="password";
$database = "db";

$mysqli = new mysqli($host, $userid, $password, $database);

if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
echo json_encode(array("success" => false, "message" => $mysqli->connect_error, "sqlerrno" => $mysqli->connect_errno));
exit();
}

$loggedIn = wp_get_current_user()->user_email;

$query = "SELECT * FROM table where email = '$loggedIn' ORDER BY 'timestamp' DESC";

$result = $mysqli->query($query);

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {


while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

            $email        = $row["email"];
            $plugin       = $row["plugin"];
            $download_url = $row["download_url"];
            $key          = $row["key"];
            $counter      = $row["counter"];
            $plugin2      = substr($plugin, 21);

            echo '<tr>';
            echo '<td>' . $plugin2 .'</td>';
            if($download_url != ''){
            echo "<td><button class='button1' onclick='clickCounter()'><a href='http://{$download_url}' target='_blank'>Download</a></button></td>";
            }else{
            echo "<td>Contact Customer Support</td>";
            }
            echo '</tr>';     
}

} else {
   echo "No Products Purchased!";
}
$mysqli->close();
```